# call VBA macro from different computer over network

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am hoping someone might be able to help me.

My problem is essentially this: A Colleague enters information into an excel, which I then have to check and pass on by email. This is fairly time-critical.

What I would like to do is

1. have the colleague press a button that calls the macros on my computer (worksheet running continuously),or
2. have my colleague email me and I have a macro in Outlook which checks for specific subject lines, or
3. he saves it on the network, and I check every minute for new files in that folder.

While the last two of these are possible, the outlook solution is - for several company policy reasons - the very last resort, and I would also like to avoid the ongoing checking for files as I am already having slight performance issues (large worksheet with lots of external links that are being feed real time).

I am also open to all other suggestions someone might have. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You need to provide more info. Such as: 1) What do the macros on your computer do? 2) Why can't this macros be run from the users Excel file 3) Why would you miss an Outlook email from your colleague in the first place

Comment: Hi brettdj, 1) The macros on my computer check that the order he gives is/are correct and within the investment policy, which is why 2) it has to be run from my workplace (legal requirement, as I do controlling) and 3) due to several company policies, it would not be a good idea to use outlook.

Comment: Also, the last two I could implement relatively easily, but as mentioned, would not like to do so.

Comment: Cant you make the checking macros available to your colleagues directly? At your end do you need to automate the checking process and pass on the email without any manual review?

Comment: Unfortunatly, from a legal standpoint I can't. It needs to be checked by an independent intermediary, and if I made it available to them, they could easily circumvent it. I do the checking process automated and without manual review, unless there's a problem. Otherwise there'd be a time problem if I am in a meeting, for example.

Comment: 3 sounds like the simplest to implement.

Comment: I don't see the cosistency in this " I do the checking process automated and without manual review, unless there's a problem.". I will look to outline solutions for 2 and 3. They will be rather lengthy.

Comment: Hi Brettdj, thanks, that is not necessary, I can do both 2 and 3. I was - as in my original post - hoping for a different solution, for the reasons explained.

Comment: Also, I don't see an inconsitency. I need to check orders before they go out to a third person, who trades them. This can be automated. It cannot be run from the originator of the trade, else he could just send the order without having checked it first. Furthermore he is legally not allowed to place an order. So the process is automated, without manual review, unless there is an invalid trade.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the third option.

Make his workbook save information to a 'queue' file or folder. Your workbook can query this queue, which should be on the network somewhere, and notify you when its changed.  Wouldn't even have to open it unless it has changed if you set it to compare modify dates, and could be small if it is saved as text or in XML format.

First option won't work because VBA framework is pretty locked down. Cross workbook macro activation isn't possible from what i understand.

Second option is more work than necessary, and VBA/Outlook will warn you every 5 minutes that its trying to access your mail folder since that's what malicious software typically does.

Like i said, the third option would be best, and his macro could be set to only write, could even encrypt the text using simple encryption methods so that others can't easily modify it if that is a concern.